# create a Map from scala.xml.NodeSeq

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have the following xml-node:

```
val xml = <fields><field name="one"></field><field name="two"></field></fields>
```

Now I would like to create a Map[String, Node] with the field-name as key.

```
for{x <- xml \ "field"} yield Map(x \ "@name" -> x)
```

Using yield above I get a List of Maps though:

```
List(Map((one,<field name="one"></field>)), Map((two,<field name="two"></field>)))
```

How do I functionally get a Map[String, Node] without going the imperative way (temp-vars) to transform the Maps in the List to the final desired Map, maybe without yield?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  xml \ "field" map { x => ((x \ "@name").text -> x) } toMap
```

Comment: its a nitpick, but the compiler complains that the toMap at the end doesn't use the dot notation (i.e .toMap)

Answer (score 4):

I guess there is an yet easier way to do this, but

```
(for{x <- xml \ "field"} yield (x \ "@name", x)).toMap
```

should work. You basically yield a sequence of tuples and convert it to a Map afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Both posted answers yield a map, but to get a Map[String, Node] you must call `(x \ "@name").text` to get the attribute value.

Comment: Quite correct, thanks (this is also an issue with the OP's original code too).